# Как сохранить открытую картинку по ftp?

Tags: php, ftp

есть скрипт с обработкой картинок, нужно картинки сразу сохранять на удаленный сервер по ftp, без локального сохранения.
Так я раньше сохранят локально

$img= new Imagick('img.png');

```
file_put_contents($path,$img);
```

Так пытаюсь сохранить сразу по ftp

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.url.ru');

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'user', 'pass');
  
ftp_fput($conn_id,$path,$img,FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Он мне выдает ошибку

> Warning: ftp_fput() expects parameter 3 to be resource, object given
> in

Что не так, вроде же ftp_fput как раз и служит для сохранения открытых файлов...

Как сохранить обработанный imagic файл сразу на ftp ?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы передаете функции объект Imagick, а не файл, который она ожидает. Сохраните в файл из $img, м передавайте этот файл функции FTP.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в вопросе написано «без локального сохранения»

Comment: @andreymal Несомненно, но с таким скриптом это не получится, да и в общем будет очень проблематично. Даже если можно получить массив данных изображения в [памяти](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189368/creating-an-image-without-storing-it-as-a-local-file) , его нельзя будет передать на сервер потоком так как это не то же самое что и содержимое файла изображения, в котором есть свой собственный формат.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov неужели в php imagick нету функции, которая запишет изображение в правильном формате в переменную вместо файла?

Comment: @andreymal по ссылке выше можно получить данные для файла, но streamить его на FTP не знаю получится ли. Хотя если подключить вот [это](https://evertpot.com/222/) и комбинировать с [примером](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189368/creating-an-image-without-storing-it-as-a-local-file) то можно получить resource для передачи в FTP функцию.